# ADF Copy Data activity - reference Source column from dynamic expression for Sink stored procedure parameter value

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I have Azure Data Factory Pipeline that has a Copy Data activity with Stored Procedure Sink. The SP takes as an input a table type parameter. Everything works fine so far. But now that SP has changed and I need to add another parameter that should be Max of one of the columns of the Source for my Copy Data activity. I cannot do this inside that SP since it is re-used by other components and takes it as input. Of course I could wrap it into another SP that would calculate that Max and then call the original SP, bu I thought better way would be if I could do that directly form ADF Pipeline. So I thought I could add a new parameter in my Sink SP and somehow get that Max using dynamic content, but I can't figure out a way to reference Source of the Copy Data activity.

Lets say the Source of Copy Data has column `Id` and I need to pass the Max value of that column to the SP Sink. Is there a way to do something like `max(@Source.Id)` in the SP's parameter value field?

Comment: which type is your source?

Comment: Steve Zhao, the source is Query, and it's resulting data set is mapped to the table type

Comment: You can try to use `lookup activity` to get maxId,and use it's output as sp's parameter.

Comment: yeah I could, but I thought there should be a way to reference the Source directly, that would be much simpler and straightforward

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware,it's impossible to reference the Source directly.So I think use `lookup activity` is an alternative to do such thing.

Hope this can help you.